# Using google OAuth v2 with laravel without a database

Tags: laravel, google-oauth

So here's my problem, i've been using laravel for about a year now, so im still kinda new to it, but there's a project that i'm working on that require me to use Google api OAuth v2, and I cannot use a database so package like passport are completely out of the question since they require a database :/

The way the app is supposed to work is :
The user open the app, fill a form and send it, when the user send the form, the app is supposed to call google's api OAuth v2 and return credentials such as email of the user currently connected to the browser, 
with the email the app decides if the person can or cannot send the form,
example :

required email domain : @acompany.com
user email needs to be: xxxxxxx@acompany.com

I really need some help on this, i've been trying solutions for the last couple of days, if you need any more info, plz just ask.

tx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/socialite), the oAuth flow will be as following:

1. Redirect user to Google
2. User logs in with Google
3. Google redirects to your app (to provided redirect uri)
4. In the `handleProviderCallback()` you have access to the current user and you can verify the user email.
5. If the user contains @acompany.com email, redirect the user to the form.

With this design the user first logs in to Google, you verify the email and show the form (if the user is allowed).

Comment: Where do you recommand me to put the code for that? 
At first i thought it was a good idea to put it in a middleware in my POST route, but im not sure its the best way.. Tx alot for answering by the way :)

Comment: You can put the code in the LoginController as described in the docs. Google on Socialite Google login, you can find multiple tutorials and the docs are pretty good.